# Does kedro data catalog accept .arrow files?

Tags: yaml, pyarrow, apache-arrow, kedro

While using [Kedro](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) I want to load some data and work with it. To do that, one has to register the data in a *conf/base/catalog.yml* file.
The [Kedro Documentation of the Data Catalog](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) explains how one can register data for Kedro to load. However, there is little to no information on how to load a [.arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2022/10/05/arrow-parquet-encoding-part-1/) file.

In the *conf/base/catalog.yml* I tried to register my data thus:

```
dataframe:
  type: arrow.ArrowDataSet
  filepath: "home/place/data.arrow"
  layer : primary
```

And ofcourse tried on different combinations from the data catalog documentation mentioned above. 
The error code I get is the following :
`DataSetError: An exception occurred when parsing config for DataSet 'dataframe': Class 'arrow.ArrowDataSet' not found or one of its dependencies has not been installed.`

I have ofcourse installed the arrow package in my environment.

Does the Kedro Data Catalog simply not accept .arrow files or is there a way to register such a format in the catalog.yml file?

Thanks in advance,

Jamal

Comment: It doesn't look like kedro supports `arrow`. But anyway, if you are going to store data as files, you should use `parquet`, not `arrow`. See examples here: https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data/data_catalog.html?highlight=parquet#example-10-loads-saves-a-parquet-file-on-local-file-system-storage-using-specified-load-and-save-arguments

Comment: hey @0x26res , That is the solution I finally went with, but the reason was only because Kedro supports .parquet. However, it sounds like you have more reasons to use parquet to save data as files. Am I right? and if yes, can you please spare some time and illuminate me? This is much appreciated, Thank you!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472727/difference-between-apache-parquet-and-arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said @0x26res, you can use the parquet dataset or others that [kedro supports](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.html). Parquet could be handled in kedro by pyarrow engine because under the hood is [pandas read_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) with 2 engines and pyarrow by default.

It may be necessary to [install dependencies to use other dataset types](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro_project_setup/dependencies.html#install-dependencies-at-a-type-level):

```
pip install kedro[pandas.ParquetDataSet]
```