# How to (de)serialize Polars DataFrame to send it over REST call?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I would like to convert `polars::frame::DataFrame` into a serializable format to send it over a REST call. For performance reasons, I would want to avoid JSON or CSV and instead use the arrow format.

While I see that there is a [`to_arrow()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_arrow.html) and [`from_arrow()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_arrow.html#polars.from_arrow) in Python. I didn't find any such functions in Rust.

How do I serialize and de-serialize a Polars DataFrame into binary format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the Arrow IPC or the Parquet formats. The differences between them are outlined in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481636/7884305).

For IPC, decoding from a [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) is done with [`IpcStreamReader`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.IpcStreamReader.html), and encoding to a [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html) is done with [`IpcStreamWriter`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.IpcStreamWriter.html).

For Parquet, decoding is done with [`ParquetReader`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.ParquetReader.html), and encoding with [`ParquetWriter`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.ParquetWriter.html).